# vagrant haltで通常の終了でなく強制終了されてしまう。

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox

**環境**
Vagrant 2.2.4
VirtualBox バージョン 5.2.28 r130011 (Qt5.6.3)
VBoxControl バージョン　5.2.28r130011
ホストos mac High Sierra 10.13.5
ゲストos Ubuntu14.04

**問題**
`vagrant halt`で終了するときにとても長い時間が掛かります。

コマンドラインを確認すると

```
==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
==> default: Forcing shutdown of VM...
```

強制終了されているように思えます。
ubuntu側の何かが上手く終了出来ずにこのような動作になると思うのですが、原因がわかりません。
詳しい方、お力を貸して頂けないでしょうか？

思い当たる節は最近アップデートをした際、VBoxControlが現在のバージョンとマッチしないと表示されプログラムが自動でアップデートしたのは良いのですが、その後、`virtualbox guest additions starting...`で止まってしまい強制的にvagrant haltしてしまったのが原因ではないかと思います。
しかし、その後vagrant upで上手く起動出来てSSHも問題ないです。`VBoxControl --version`でバージョン確認してもちゃんとアップデートされていました。

**全部は長すぎて載せれないので個人的にここでないかと思うところ**
vagrant halt --debugでエラーの内容が詳しく出てきたのですが、意味はよく分かりません。

```
==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
    default: Guest communication could not be established! This is usually because
    default: SSH is not running, the authentication information was changed,
    default: or some other networking issue. Vagrant will force halt, if
    default: capable.
==> default: Forcing shutdown of VM...

ERROR warden: Error occurred: The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
```

**GuestAdditionsが動いてないみたいな事が書かれているインストールはされている。**

```
DEBUG ssh: Exit status: 1
DEBUG vbguest-machine: Current states for VM 'default' are : guest_version=5.2.28 : host_version=5.2.28 : running=false
 INFO interface: warn: [default] GuestAdditions seems to be installed (5.2.28) correctly, but not running.
[default] GuestAdditions seems to be installed (5.2.28) correctly, but not running.
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["/usr/local/bin/VBoxManage", "showvminfo", "dcad3a13-b345-4ff4-9e5c-fb4dbdcdf169", "--machinereadable"]
DEBUG subprocess: Command not in installer, not touching env vars.
 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: stdout: name="ubuntu1404-server_default_1514889379163_78359"
```

**vagrant up --debug、vagrant halt --debugどちらでも最後は同じエラー**

```
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

shutdown -h now

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:
```

Comment: SSH でなく `vagrant ssh` はできますか?

Comment: `ssh vagrant` でログインして、 `shutdown -h now` を打つとシャットダウンできますか？（そのコマンドがエラーになっているようですので、何かメッセージが出ませんか）

Comment: Guest Additions が動いていないのは、`sudo systemctl enable vboxadd.service` で有効化できると思います。（詳しくは [VirtualBox上のServerLinuxへのGuestAdditionsの導入方法 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/miyagaw61/items/bd577a2e08ec04081235) を参照）

Answer (score 0):

月並みですが、まずは/var/log/messagesあたりの確認から始められ亭はいかがでしょうか。
その他、/var/log配下のファイル、ディレクトリにシャットダウン時のログとか出てないですか？

Comment: vagrant halt --debugで実行時の様子が出るようになりました。SSHのところでつまづいているように伺えるのですが、SSHで接続は可能です。

Comment: >vagrant halt --debugで実行時の様子が出るようになりました。
出力内容を開示しないと、この先誰もわからないかと・・・

Comment: 全ては長すぎるため個人的にここでないかと思うものを選びました。debugでは同じ事を何度もループしているように見えました。